# Cancel Request with browser

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, web-applications

Assume this scenario: I send a request to my server(apache tomcat) from a browser(firefox). The response come after about 2 minutes from server. How can I cancel this request in a way that my server do not continue for making the response ?
When a user sent a request to the server, it is common to go to another link(or menu or cancel the request) of application and it is so important for developers to cancel such these cases and so reduce the server load.
OK then, I want a technique to detect such incoming requests which are sent to my server and cancel all actions for making the response for client( because the client is not waiting for server response anymore).
I couldn't find useful information in google and stack.
I also set **keep-alive-timeout** in my **server.xml**, but nothing happened!
I also read this topic [cancle request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507778/what-happens-in-an-application-server-tomcat-etc-when-a-client-request-is-can) , but it didn't help me.

So please help me to solve this issue ...

Comment: sorry mate you can not do it.  Once the server code has its grubby hands on the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the request sending content to its outputstream (and flushing it).
If a user cancels the request, the servlet will loss the connection to the browser and then, sending content to the outputstream will throw a ClientAbortException making the process stop.

Try this:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1 id=\"count\"></h1>");
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            out.print("<script>document.getElementById(\"count\").innerHTML=\"" + i + "\";</script>");
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Stoped due to " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```